# Why does text in UILabel appear to have a space when replacingString is used?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel

Im using this to fill in a UILabel:

```
storeName.text = [self.receivedLocation.name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Store" withString:@""];
```

But this results in an apparent space inserted at the beginning left-side of the label.  How can i fix that?

Comment: What's the value of `self.receivedLocation.name`?

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you give the label a fixed width in IB? If it's set to "Size To Fit Content", which labels are by default, it should resize appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If your string has a value such as `Store some more stuff` then the result will be `some more stuff` with the leading space still in place.

Try this:

```
// Get original text
NSString *label = self.receivedLocation.name;
// Remove occurrences of "Store"
label = [label stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Store" withString:@""];
// Trim any leading and/or trailing whitespace
label = [label stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
storeName.text = label;
```